# Maximization under non-linear constraints in MATLAB using fmincon

Tags: matlab, math, constraints, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve maximize a function s.t. 14 constraints and with 15 variables.
Some of them are linear, some are not. They are all equations (no inequalities).

I have tries using 'fsolve' and 'solve', using lagrange (ended up with 29 equations and 30 variables) - that didn't go that well...

I moved on to fmincon. I've set a script with an objective function in a file named objectfun.m:

```
function f = objectfun(x,I,rho)

% SWAPPING VARIABLE NAMES FOR READABILITY:
w = x(1);
t = x(2);
beta = x(3);
r = x(4);

% VALUE FUNCTION TO BE MINIMIZES:
f = -(rho*w*(1-t)+beta+I*(1+(1-t)*r));
```

I have set another one with the constraints:

```
function [c, ceq] = confun(x,...
    Bs,Bu,sigma_s,sigma_u,rho,c_bar,I,A,alpha)

% SWAPPING VARIABLE NAMES FOR READABILITY:
w = x(1);
t = x(2);
beta = x(3);
r = x(4);
vum = x(5);
vsm = x(6);
ms = x(7);
cstar = x(8);
zs = x(9);
zu = x(10);
H = x(11);
K = x(12);
Y = x(13);
L = x(14);
mu = x(15);

% INEQUILITY CONSTRAINTS:
c = [];

% EQUALITY CONSTRAINTS:
ceq = [ms-Bs*vsm^sigma_s;               % 1
    mu-Bu*vum^sigma_u;                  % 2
    (1+r*(1-t))*cstar-(1-rho)*w*(1-t);  % 3
    zs-cstar/c_bar;                     % 4
    zu-1+zs;                            % 5
    H-(cstar^2)/(2*c_bar);              % 6
    I-K-H;                              % 7
    A*(K^alpha)*(L^(1-alpha))-Y;        % 8
    L-(zs+rho*zu+ms+rho*mu);            % 9
    w-(1-alpha)*A*(K/L)^alpha;          % 10
    r-alpha*A*(K/L)^(alpha-1);          % 11
    t*Y-beta*(1+ms+mu);                 % 12
    vum-rho*w*(1-t)-beta;               % 13
    vsm-w*(1-t)-beta];                  % 14
```

And a main script:

```
%% Parameters:
Bs =0.0;
Bu =0.0;
sigma_s = 1.5;
sigma_u = 1.5;
rho = 0.33;
c_bar = 6;
I = 3;
A = 1;
alpha = 0.33;

%% Numeric Solution:
x0 = 0.5*ones(length(var_names),1);

objective = @(x)objectfun(x,I,rho);

constraints = @(x)confun(x,...
    Bs,Bu,sigma_s,sigma_u,rho,c_bar,I,A,alpha);

options = optimoptions(@fmincon);

[s,fval] = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],constraints,options);
```

The question:
The solution is nonsense. I went over the equations many times - let's assume their good! (please...[= )

1. Did I choose the right application for my problem (fmincon)?
2. Is there a problem with the structure or in the code specifically?
3. Do you have any suggestions on how to make my life a bit easier?
4. I plan on iterating on the solution using different parameter values. Is there any way of verifying the solution, for a given set, just to see if the solution is correct?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can do:

1. Provide reasonable bounds on all variables. This will prevent the solver to  go to areas where things do not make sense, and where the functions (and gradients) can not be evaluated.
2. Provide a better starting point.
3. Provide gradients. Unless you have a system that can do automatic differentiation it is often important to provide correct and exact gradients. (Some solvers may also require second derivatives).
4. If you have a known solution for a given data set, pass this on as initial point and see what happens. Further you can fix this solution by setting lower and upper-bounds equal to this known solution and then see what happens then.
5. Try a more powerful modeling system/solver. E.g. GAMS with CONOPT is often used in economic modeling and provides automatic differentiation and gives often better feedback if something goes wrong. This is a small problem so you should be able to run it with the free student/demo version (http://gams.com/download/). The other suggestions can be applied here also.

Comment: Thank you very much! The bounds -  I put in the inequality constraints in the the constraints function (in 'c', specifically) ?  And I'll definitely try Gams, thanks for the advise.

Comment: No. Use lb,ub. The help page on fmincon helps with help on how to use it.